# How change default version curl and soap in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, soap

Actually I have this config for curl:

```
apt-cache search php | grep -i curl
php-curl - CURL module for PHP [default]
php7.4-curl - CURL module for PHP
```

I want change default version php7.4

I have tried this:
sudo apt update

```
sudo apt install php7.4-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php7.4-curl is already the newest version (7.4.3-4ubuntu2.10).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
```

In php.ini is enabled, but in CMS I obtain CURL AND SOAP is not enabled.

The soap is the same:

```
apt-cache search php | grep -i soap
libnusoap-php - SOAP toolkit for PHP
php-soap - SOAP module for PHP [default]
php7.4-soap - SOAP module for PHP
python3-pysimplesoap - simple and lightweight SOAP Library (Python 3)
```

How change to default version php7.4?

Comment: "_In php.ini is enabled_" Did you edit the correct `php.ini`? Did you restart your server after making the changes? Does it show up as enabled on a `phpinfo()` page?

Comment: _"but in CMS I obtain CURL AND SOAP is not enabled"_ - So what exactly is your question? Why they aren't enabled in your CMS or how to change the default versions? Those are very different questions. There are also two different php.ini files on Ubuntu. One for the web server and one for CLI. Are they enabled in both and, as the previous comment asks, if it's enabled for the web server, did you restart it? Or possibly restarted PHP-FPM, if that is what you're using?

Comment: Yes, I have tested all you say, php.ini from apache and restart sever, in phpinfo show enabled, but really not enable, because Prestashop say not enabled...

Comment: Well let's see, the CMS is Prestashop, when I install a module it tells me that CURL and SOAP are not enabled on my server. In fact you don't have any option to enable CURL or SOAP from PRestashop. The reboot is obviously what I did.
I am using apache, php and mysql.

With the command that I have shown before, it tells me that version 7.4 of each one is not set by default, it should be.